# ASUSTek Firmware update

Tags: bios, updates, asus-laptop, firmware

I went to optional updates, and chose the ASUSTeK Firmware update (ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. - Firmware - 10.1.2.310) and restarted it, it said it would reboot in 60 seconds but i turned the laptop off before that and unplugged the device. It turned on and says that restart is required. Is there any way to undo this? I don't want to get the update

Comment: Why do you not want the update? Just let it update.

Comment: Will it not cause any problems or require anything?

Comment: 99.99% chance it will not cause any problems. I won't require anything other than maybe a couple of seconds.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.